# Asp.net "allowDefinition=MachineToApplication" error

Tags: asp.net

I have edited the relevant .cs files in my web service. But after editing I end up with the following error: "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS." Can you please let me know what should be the problem? Because there are no Warnings, no issues, it's just one error. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have sub folders with their own web.config files in your project?

Comment: Yes I have three web.config files in total. Two of them are with different codes and one is just created after testing the project with this error.

Answer (score 2):

This is normally caused when you have a web aapp/virtual directory containing a Web.config, then you add another Web.config in a directory underneath it. The lower directory needs to be configured as a Virtual Directory in IIS.

Comment: I have created the virtual directory but still it gives me the same error my friend. Please let me know what should I do to get resolved! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is mentioned in your message. Your folder containing this website is not configured as an application in IIS. I suggest you to check whether or not your folder is a marked as a virtual directory or an application in your IIS.

To configure your sub directory as an application:

> Goto IIS-
>
> In your virtual directory where you have this folder, right click on
>   it and goto properties-
>
> You ill find create option-
>
> Click on it.

Now your folder is an application and you should get rid of the error

**Update**: To create a virtual directory-

> 1.Open IIs
>
> 2.Double Click on websites
>
> 3.Right Click Default Web site
>
> 4.New-Virtual Directory-Next- Give some name for alias-Now select your folder containing website-Next-Next-Finish.

Now run your website.

Comment: Thank you fr your reply. It is not marked as virtual directory, but I have tried it creating a virtual application on IIS but still I am getting the same error. Is it because the version problem with Visual Studio, because right now I am using VS2010 and the application was developed using the previous version. If possible give me some other ideas and ways through which I can  run my web service properly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are in the advance version than the application so that may not be the issue. Do this: copy your folder containing the site into a separate location, then goto IIS and create virtual directory with path upto that folder. If you have any other sub directories in this folder with another web.config, follow the steps in answer after you create the virtual directory. Let me know if that worked

Comment: I only have the following options: Explore, Edit permissions, add application, add virtual directory, manage application, refresh, remove, deploy, switch to content view. Which one I should select?

Comment: My update was for IIS 5.1. You will have similar options if you are using a higher version. Go ahead with the clues

Comment: I have created the virtual directory as you said. but after running I am getting the same error allowDefinition=MachineToApplication.. But I have noticed that when I created the Virtual Directory I tried to test the connection/seettings from the IIS (7.5), it authenticates the connection but it says it is not authorized. So, what should I do?